# difference between npm install react-router-dom and npm install --save react-router-dom command

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

difference between npm install react-router-dom and npm install --save react-router-dom command

I tried both commands and got same result so can't understand what the actual working  difference between these commands

Comment: Latest NPM docs https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install do not even have `--save` as an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from version 5 `npm` will save the package to your dependencies by default. For previous versions you needed `--save` flag to do that.

More info: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5108

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of npm v5 or greater, by default, it will be saved without the --save flag.

Prior to npm 5, the --save command will also save the package name under the package.json file under the dependencies object.

This will ensure than if this project was to be pulled/cloned on a different computer, you can type npm install to install all the dependencies listed under the package.json.

Whereas without --save, the dependency will not be put into package.json dependencies list. And when you type npm install in a new environment, you will be missing that package.

Comment: You made the answer clearer by explaining what the --save does